# Operator Overloading in C# for a VB.NET person

Tags: c#

Consider This Class which overloads the = Operator for the Person Class. This works in VB.NET:

```vb
Public Class Person

    Public Sub New(ByVal FirstName As String, ByVal LastName As String)
        _FirstName = FirstName
        _LastName = LastName
    End Sub

    Private _LastName As String
    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return _LastName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _LastName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _FirstName As String
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return _FirstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _FirstName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal Person1 As Person, ByVal Person2 As Person) As Boolean
        Return Not (Person1 = Person2)
    End Operator


    Public Shared Operator =(ByVal Person1 As Person, ByVal Person2 As Person) As Boolean
        Return Person1.FirstName = Person2.FirstName AndAlso Person1.LastName = Person2.LastName
    End Operator

    Public Class Test

        Public Sub TestIt()

            Dim P1 As New Person("f1", "l1")
            Dim P2 As Person = Nothing

            Dim IsEqual As Boolean = False

            If P1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso P2 IsNot Nothing Then

                If P1 = P2 Then
                    IsEqual = True
                End If

            End If

        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

And the same class in C#:

```
public Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    _FirstName = FirstName;
    _LastName = LastName;
}

private string _LastName;
public string LastName
{
    get { return _LastName; }
    set { _LastName = value; }
}

private string _FirstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _FirstName; }
    set { _FirstName = value; }
}

public static bool operator !=(Person Person1, Person Person2)
{
    return !(Person1 == Person2);
}


public static bool operator ==(Person Person1, Person Person2)
{
    return Person1.FirstName == Person2.FirstName && Person1.LastName == Person2.LastName;
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestIt()
    {
        Person P1 = new Person("f1", "l1");
        Person P2 = null;

        bool IsEqual = false;


        if (P1 != null && P2 != null)
        {
            if (P1 == P2)
            {
                IsEqual = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the C# class, how can I test to see if a `Person` Object is `null` before calling the overloaded `==` operator function if the function is used in testing to see if it is `null`. That is, is there an equivalent counterpart function to VB's `Is Nothing` that is separate from the `==` test? It seems like C# uses `==` for both.

I tried `object.IsEqual`; that also looked wrong.

Comment: The equivalent to VB.NET's "Is Nothing" is "== null" in C#.

Comment: @LookitsPuck: The point is that the `==` operator is overloaded for that type. VB.NET has separate overloads for `=` and `Is`.

Comment: Then you'll need to check what the reference is equal to. ReferenceEquals on the given object and compare to null.

Comment: @LookitsPuck Isn't the C# 'equivalent' of Is Nothing `== default(Person)`? Granted `== null` is correct for reference types.. but not for value types..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, he's working with objects in this regard, no? That said, from MSDN on default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx FWIW, the default keyword wasn't available in all versions of .NET/VS.

Comment: @LookitsPuck It was introduced in C# 2, and it's not just applicable to generic types.. which is why I suggested it :)

Answer (score 3):

BTW, since you're implementing `==` you should also override Equals (and GetHashCode).

A simple way to do this is to implement `IEquatable<Person>`:

```
public bool Equals(Person other)
{
    return other != null &&
           FirstName == other.FirstName &&
           LastName == other.LastName;
}
```

Then override Equals:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
    var other = o as Person;
    return other != null && this.Equals(other);
}
```

Finally `==` is just:

```
public static bool operator ==(Person left, Person right)
{
    return object.Equals(left, right);
}

public static bool operator !=(Person left, Person right)
{
    return !(left == right);
}
```

([object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) hands `null` cases correctly.)

Comment: this.Equals(other) will intimate loop

Comment: @ColeJohnson: No, it will call the `Equals(Person)` overload

Comment: I accepted too fast. The check P2 != null yeilds the same Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Comment: @Chad: can you explain your comment further?

Answer (score 1):

Check for `null` in your overloaded operator too using `object.ReferenceEquals`:

```
public static bool operator ==(Person Person1, Person Person2)
{
    if(object.ReferenceEquals(Person1, null)) {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(Person2, null);
    } else if(object.ReferenceEquals(Person2, null)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return Person1.FirstName == Person2.FirstName && Person1.LastName == Person2.LastName;
    }
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```
return object.ReferenceEquals(person1, person2) || (
           !object.ReferenceEquals(person1, null)
        && !object.ReferenceEquals(person2, null)
        && person1.FirstName == person2.FirstName
        && person1.LastName  == person2.LastName);
```

Comment: The first one works, the second is, ironically, StackOverflow without the .com.

Comment: @Chad: Yeah, the `!= null` thing. Change them to `!object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)`.